# Unusual UPDATE syntax in stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.3

I need help understanding this stored procedure I found in a legacy system that I'm auditing.  In particular I can't understand the UPDATE command inside the IF conditional: `UPDATE authors.author_id ...`.

```
DECLARE

    p_mem_id ALIAS FOR $1;
    p_auth_id ALIAS FOR $2;

    res     bool ;
    v_rec   authors.author_gov_id%ROWTYPE;

    BEGIN
        res := 0;
        SELECT INTO v_rec * FROM authors.author_gov_id WHERE author_id = p_auth_id;

        IF FOUND THEN
              UPDATE authors.author_id = (SELECT gov_id FROM authors.gov_id WHERE mem_id=p_mem_id);
        ELSE
              .. snip ..
        END IF;

        RETURN res;
    END;
```

I'm find this baffling because this update statement seems to be unsupported syntax[1] in my version of PSQL (No SET, and direct assignment), and because there is no relation called `authors.author_id` in my database (nothing in pg_proc either).

```
my_database=# \d authors.author_id;
Did not find any relation named "authors.author_id".
```

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-update.html

Comment: I highly doubt that this code can compile.

Comment: Is this the real function?!?  If not, can you post it and include the DDL for the three referenced tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, that's invalid syntax.

However, when you create a function, the actual function code (the "body") is passed as a string and is not parsed by the part that checks the basic `create function` syntax. That string is handed over to the "language" that is specified for further validation.

The configuration option [`check_function_bodies`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CHECK-FUNCTION-BODIES) controls if this checking is done when you create a function.

If that is set to `off`, the body is not validated and the `create function()` succeeds even if the body is invalid.

So the following successfully creates the function:

```
set check_function_bodies=off;

create function invalid()
  returns void
as
$$
begin
  update foo.bar = 'this is so wrong';
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I guess the function code you see in that database was created that way.

---

A valid use case for this, is to create functions that depend on each other without having to think about the order in which they have to be  created.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid SQL syntax, and postgres will barf when you actually call this function.

After seeing the comment base suggest that I wasn't crazy for being confused, I found a staging database with this stored procedure installed, and attempted to cause the UPDATE clause to trigger - resulting in the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "="
LINE 1: UPDATE authors.author_id = (SELECT gov_id FROM authors...
                                ^
QUERY:  UPDATE authors.author_id = (SELECT gov_id FROM authors.gov_id WHERE mem_id=p_mem_id)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function authors.copy_govid(integer,integer) line 15 at SQL statement
```